# CKEDITOR.replace(); is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor

Well i am using VS2010 to integrate CKeditor in MVC 3. I am successively able to integrate it but I am facing issue with customize toolbar. I have config.js under Scripts/ckeditor folder. I have create a copy of config.js and placed it under the root directory(i.e testmvc) and renamed it to "myconfig.js". 
Now my config.js looks like this :

> CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
>
> // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
>
> // config.language = 'fr';
>
> // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
>
> CKEDITOR.replace('editor1',
>
> {
>
> ```
> customConfig :  'testmvc1/myconfig.js'
> ```
>
> } );
>
> };

and my "myconfig.js" looks like this:

> CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
>
> {
>     // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
>
> // config.language = 'fr';
>
> // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
>
> config.toolbar = 'Full';
>
> config.toolbar_Full =
>
> [
>
> > { name: 'document', items: ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'DocProps', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates'] },
> >     ];
>
> };

Now i want that default config.js should redirect it to my custom "myconfig.js" so that i can use my customized toolbar, but the replace command is not working. It is throwing me an error when i launch the website. Please suggest me something because i tried everything on the net

Comment: even tried this link which is closest to my post [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754798/specifying-a-custom-configuration-file-for-ckeditor

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have config.js and myconfig.js? You need one of them (the latter probably). Then in your HTML just add `<script>` tag with:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    customConfig:  'testmvc1/myconfig.js'
});
```

BTW if you have an error on the console, please attach it next time. We're not magicians.

Comment: Config.js comes with  CKeditor folder. So if i declare my customized toolbar in config.js and do a update on CKeditor folder i'll lose my customized toolbar. This is why i created myconfig.js and placed it under root of my website i.e. testmvc1 and direct the ckeditor to load it during run time, which i am trying to do through  replace command. As for the error, it is a page error stating "exception thrown and not caught".

Answer (score 0):

The call to load the editor needs to be in the file with the textarea. Either in the head inside the onload event or after the textarea is called.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1',
    {
        customConfig :  'testmvc1/myconfig.js'    
    } );
</script>
```

Here's the page from the developer's guide: [Developers_Guide: Integration](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration)

---

To call your custom config within the default config file, try this:

```
config.customConfig = 'testmvc1/myconfig.js';
```

---

Possible causes of error:

Try reversing the order of your toolbar config assignments:

```
config.toolbar_Full =
[
    { name: 'document', items: ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'DocProps', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates'] }
];

config.toolbar = 'Full';
```

You need to define the toolbar before you assign it.

---

Also, something that might cause the error is the comma between the closing brace and the closing bracket `'Templates'] }, ];`